# Linking input of remote command executed with Paramiko SSH to local Python console

Tags: python, shell, unix, ssh, paramiko

I am using Python to ssh over to remote server using Paramiko and run shell script to execute commands

.py file:

```py
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
print("Connected")
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(myscript)

# read the standard output and print it
print(stdout.read().decode())
# print errors if there are any
err = stderr.read().decode()
if err:
    print(err)
ssh.close()
```

Unix script:

```sh
cd /usr/data
pwd
read -r username  
echo "$username"
```

The output will be:

```
/usr/data
```

It doesn't allow be to enter the input for username variable and doesn't display it.

How can I achieve this using Python (pycharm ide) and Unix?

Answer (score 0):

You are maybe looking for:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(myscript)

interactive_shell(stdin.channel)
```

Where `interactive_shell` comes from [Paramiko `interactive.py` demo](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/main/demos/interactive.py).